# mySQL SELECT timestamp(now()-3000);

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I'm trying to make a query which brings back results based on a timestamp, say an interval of 30 minutes.

So what I figured out is that I can

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE ts BETWEEN timestamp(now()-3000) AND timestamp(now())
```

So this will query everything from x with timestamps in column ts within the last 30 minutes.

However, this only works after now() is past the yyyy-mm-dd HH:30:00 mark because anytime before it will result in NULL... this is rather cumbersome and I don't understand why it won't just subtract the friggin minutes from the hour!

Please help me out! I couldn't find any other method of doing a query within the last 30 minutes, that is what I'm trying to achieve.

Best regards,

John

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE ts BETWEEN timestamp(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)) AND timestamp(NOW())
```

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE ts BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE AND NOW();
```

Answer (score 4):

```sql
SELECT * FROM x 
WHERE ts BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, -30, NOW()) AND NOW();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to realize that timestamp() returns a unix timestamp in seconds. 3000 seconds is not 30 minutes, it should be 1800 seconds. try that

Comment: @Theveloper ah it should be unix_timestamp, didn't see that part. A timestamp is in a different format that you can't so coherently do math with.

Answer (score 1):

For me, what worked is following query

```
select * from x where (now() - ts) < 1800000
```

1800000 is 30 minutes, because 60000 ms is 1 minute

Comment: 6000ms equals to 6 seconds, not a minute.

Comment: That might defeat the use of an index on ts

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use DATE_ADD() and DATE_SUB() operators for dates.  Take a look at the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (`yourdb`) WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE AND NOW();
```